# Why didn't Jesus write books of his teachings but charge his apostles to spread the Gospel?

Tags: life-of-jesus

I have studied for years, found new writings from discoveries of Archeologists, but not one writing or book or Idea written by Jesus himself. All is hearsay if taken to a court of law to confirm the sayings of Jesus. Why didn't Jesus write himself the Ideas preached by the Apostles? wouldn't that have resolved questions on authority , divinity, and Nature of God?

Comment: Are first hand witnesses to be considered to be guilty of hearsay? The Apostles and Evangelists all died protecting their faith in Jesus Christ!

Comment: This appears to be a request to mind read across a time span of 2000 years.  It's hard enough to do that without the temporal obstacle.  (In other words, speculation)

Comment: I spent several hours crafting an answer for you. If you'd like a copy of it, feel free to communicate with me via email. My address is in my Stack Exchange profile/bio page. Don

Answer (score 0):

#### God wants us to do it.

---

Deuteronomy 31:19

> Now therefore write ye this song for you, and teach it the children of
>   Israel: put it in their mouths, that this song may be a witness for me
>   against the children of Israel.

Deuteronomy 17:19

> he shall read therein all the days of his life: that he may learn to
>   fear the Lord his God, to keep all the words of this law and these
>   statutes, to do them

All the preachings will lead into one single point → '**God loves us all**'.

John 21:25 says - '*And there are also many other things which Jesus did, which, if they should be written every one, I suppose that even the world itself could not contain the books that should be written. Amen*'